# Excel VBA: before, after or change event for combobox automatically updating another?

Tags: excel, events, combobox, beforeupdate, vba

On my userform I have couple of comboboxes: Contractor, Product, Category, Unit. All of them are filled with data from MS SQL database (2012) and then the userform executes a stored procedure and inserts new records. I would like to build a dynamic form where comboboxes update automatically based on the choice from previous combobox.

When a Contractor is chosen from the list I would like the Product list to narrow down and display only products linked with the contrator (using SELECT statment). Then I would like the category and unit to fill automatically based on product chosen.
Of course e.g when new product is typed in, full list in category and unit combobox would display so this will require if statements.

My problem is which event to use ? Before, after update or change event ? Or maybe there are other options to do this ?

I did some reading about these events and it seems that change event wouldn't be a good choice:
"Avoid creating two or more controls having Change events that affect each other — for example, two text boxes that update each other"
but I am not feeling the difference well enough as I haven't used before/after event yet. If any code of what I have done so far might be relevant, please let me know and I'll edit the post.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the direction of the changes is only one way. From what you described, you wouldn't have the problem of having two comboboxes changing each other, because the contractor changes the product and the product changes the category and unit. As long as the product's `_Change` event doesn't change the contractor (which could fire its `_Change` event, causing a chain of `_Change` event calls) you are okay. Same thing with the product -- category and product -- unit relationships.

Comment: Well, in theory I could start with Product instead of Contractor becasue the Product can be obtain from different Contractors. But I thought of using the form rather in one direction and designed comboboxes order that way.

What if I didn't ? Which event should I use then or more generally how should I proceed when I would like e.g. Contractor and Product to affect each other?

Comment: What you are trying to avoid is bouncing back and forth between events, to no end. You can have the Product_Change update the Contractor, as long as by doing so you don't trigger the Contractor's_Change event (which has code to update the Product's_Change event). If you make sure to avoid this, you're okay.
Note: You can suppress events from being fired by using `Application.EnableEvents = False`. Doing so is tricky, because you would need to make sure to set `EnableEvents` to true when you're done making changes, otherwise no events will fire from there on out.

Comment: I've decided to go with after update Product event, as Change event fires with any character inserted. I can type in a new Product so that could cause errors with Category and Unit combobox as I would need in this case full category list to pick one for new Product.  It works correctly with after update event.